# How to use results of a procedure inside table value function in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I want to parametrize a procedure to use its results in other scripts.
the procedures do union all similar tables and after doing group aggregation return a new table.
I wrote following code but it gives error:
'Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a function.'
What is the solution to use the query as a function?

```
    `ALTER FUNCTION monthly_series 
(
    @cum_income varchar(max),
    @this_month_income varchar(max)
    )
RETURNS @tbl TABLE 
(
        symbol varchar(max),
        tracing_no bigint,
        year bigint,
        month bigint,
        period bigint,
        revised bigint,
        fiscal_month bigint,
        elapsed_months bigint,
        published_g_date datetime2,
        sum_cum_income bigint,
        sum_this_month_income bigint
)
AS
BEGIN
Declare @SQL varchar(max) =''

Select @SQL = @SQL +'Union All Select *,
dbo.fiscal_month(yearEndToDate) as fiscal_month,
dbo.elapsed_months(yearEndToDate,month) as elapsed_months
From sqlDB.dbo.'+TABLE_NAME+' '
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE COLUMN_NAME like 'symbol' and TABLE_NAME in (
  select DISTINCT 'master_monthly_hist_'+ins_code+'_1' as master_monthly_hist_name from symbol_section(58))
  ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
Set @SQL = Stuff(@SQL,1,10,'')
Set @SQL='select symbol,tracing_no,year,month,period,revised,fiscal_month,elapsed_months,published_g_date,
sum('+@cum_income+') as sum_cum_income,sum('+@this_month_income+') as sum_this_month_income
from ('+@SQL+') d
where row_type=''Sale_item'' 
group by symbol,tracing_no,year,month,period,revised,fiscal_month,elapsed_months,published_g_date
'
    INSERT INTO @tbl exec (@SQL)
    RETURN
END
GO`
```

Comment: Dynamic SQL is not allowed within a table-valued or scalar-valued function

Comment: So what is the solution to make the query reusable?

Comment: Rethink the Dynamic SQL approach

Comment: I created a procedure from the query and it worked.

Comment: Well done.  I should have been more clear.   I just assumed you wanted a TVF so that it could be consumed within a CROSS APPLY for example.

Answer (score 1):

As John said dynamic sql is not allowed within an inline table function, so I changed it to procedure approach as follow and it worked:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE monthly_series (@SUF varchar(max), @cum_income varchar(max),@this_month_income  varchar(max))
AS 
BEGIN
    Declare @SQL varchar(max) =''
    Select @SQL = @SQL +'Union All Select *,
    dbo.fiscal_month(yearEndToDate) as fiscal_month,
    dbo.elapsed_months(yearEndToDate,month) as elapsed_months
    From sqlDB.dbo.'+TABLE_NAME+' '
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE COLUMN_NAME like 'symbol' and TABLE_NAME in (
      select DISTINCT 'master_monthly_hist_'+ins_code+'_'+@SUF as master_monthly_hist_name from symbol_section(58))
      ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
    Set @SQL = Stuff(@SQL,1,10,'')
    Set @SQL='select symbol,tracing_no,year,month,period,revised,fiscal_month,elapsed_months,published_g_date,
    sum('+@cum_income+') as sum_'+@cum_income+',sum('+@this_month_income+') as sum_'+@this_month_income+'
    from ('+@SQL+') d
    where row_type=''Sale_item'' 
    group by symbol,tracing_no,year,month,period,revised,fiscal_month,elapsed_months,published_g_date
    '
    EXEC(@SQL)
END

GO 
exec dbo.monthly_series '1','cum_income','this_month_income'
```

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I usually use underline instead of spaces.Where do you think this code could be changed to use QuoteName() ?

Comment: For example, `From sqlDB.dbo.'+TABLE_NAME+' '` would be safer written as `From sqlDB.dbo.'+ QuoteName( TABLE_NAME ) +' '`. While it may not be an issue in your code at the moment, changing the code to handle additional tables or borrowing the code for another purpose could expose it to errors and SQL injection attacks. Aside: I'm not sure why code _like_ `WHERE COLUMN_NAME like 'symbol'` is so common. Using `like` with a pattern that has no wildcards is not clearer than `WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'symbol'`.